# How do I filter and defilter an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array:

```
arr = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34]
```

I'd like to filter the array in the same way as `select` but also separately gather all the elements that fail the condition:

```
[evens, odds] = arr.split_filter {|p| p % 2 == 0}
# evens = [2, 8, 34]
# odds  = [1, 1, 3, 5, 13, 21]
```

I could do

```
evens = arr.select {|p| p % 2 == 0}
odds  = arr.select {|p| p % 2 != 0}
```

But that seems inefficient. Does anyone know of a function that works like `split_filter`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for [Enumerable#partition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition):

```
arr = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34]

evens, odds = arr.partition{|a| a % 2 == 0}

evens # => [2, 8, 34]
odds # => [1, 1, 3, 5, 13, 21]
```

Or, shorter version:

```
evens, odds = arr.partition(&:even?)
```

Answer (score 1):

We could always use `Enum#group_by` for the same.

```
arr = [20,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34]
even,odd = arr.group_by(&:even?).values_at(true,false)
even #=> [20, 2, 8, 34]
odd #=> [1, 1, 3, 5, 13, 21]
```